# How to retrieve my DB data using groupby for storing it into my C# Struct?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have one DB Table named final_mark and it contains student test marks in question wise.This is my table structure.
[image]

And this is my C# struct and created the array of my struct

```
struct finalMarks
        {
            public string studId;
            public Dictionary<string, int> Ques_Mark;
        };
        private finalMarks[] finalMark;
```

So, Now i want to store data from the table into this struct in stud_id wise...

for example,

```
     my finalMark[0].studId="s1"
        finalMark[0].Ques_Mark should contain following elements

              "q1"->8
              "q5"->6
```

like that my `finalMark[1]` contains the details of `stud_id "s2"`...

Is this possible to write a query using groupby or some other functions in sql(MYSQL)?

please suggest me a way to get this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data from the database using SQL, you'd just need a query like one of these.

```
-- All the final marks for one student on one test.
select ques_id, final_mark
from final_mark
where test_id = 1 and stud_id = 's1';
```

There's no hint in your data or your description that it makes sense to add the final_marks together. (Imagine you were recording temperature. It doesn't make sense to add 20 degrees to 15 degrees.) But if it *does* make sense, you can get the total final marks for each test and each student like this.

```
select test_id, stud_id, sum(final_mark) sum_of_final_mark
from final_mark
group by test_id, stud_id
```